Updating microservice to Springboot 3.2+ needs spring.config.import=bootstrap.properties
I have two microservices which almost has the same dependencies but when I update both to latest springboot version 3.2+ then only one microservice fails to load properties from boostrap property file and it needs spring.config.import=bootstrap.properties to be added in application property file, whereas other microservice with same spring boot version works fine loading properties from both bootstrap and application property files without adding spring.config.import property and hence wanted to understand why there is different behaviour in both microservices

There are nothing like this
spring.config.import=bootstrap.properties

You create 2 files

bootstrap.properties (this file will load first, it is not mandatory). This file often tells where to looking for Spring Cloud Config microservice server .

application.properties (this file will load later, it is often mandatory)



Yeah but boostrap loads only logging and vault related properties whereas other properties defined in it are not loaded. I have another sample microservice that uses same spring boot version where all properties defined in bootstrap properties file are loaded

Even in the microservice which didn't load certain properties from bootstrap happened only after updating to latest springboot version 3.2+ whereas by using previous spring boot version all the properties are loaded from boostrap property file

If you don't mind, you can share your github repository.
